# Firestore database security without rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

I store data in a Cloud Firestore database. Users in my app don´t need to create an account to get data and they can also write data without the need to login.

Google reminds me every few days that my database is insecure and can be abused by anyone. How can I improve it without accessing Auth variables?

Note: my app offers and provides service that's why the rules are set to public. I use storage so the users can submit an image and description of a bug in the app. It uses a mix of Realtime and Firestore databases. Here is a look at the public rules.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if
          request.time < timestamp.date(2023, 12, 30);
       }
     }
   }
```

check the screenshots please. >>
[screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BI7lA.jpg)
[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpSRD.jpg)
[screenshot3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6qaE.jpg)

Comment: Why not implement authentication?

Comment: I feel that user that have to register to submit or access a service ain't needed and that affect the user experience if he was in need or rush to get things fixed. add to that that  the need to track everything for getting and submitting the form. like from which user etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your last comment, if you don't want to implement the Firebase Authentication, then the security rules won't be much of a help. If you think that somehow, the Firebase Authentication with a provider will affect the user experience, then I recommend you [authenticate your users anonymously](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth). In this way, you'll be able to secure your Firestore database accordingly.

Comment: That will enable the users to read and write as if it was a public database?. I'll be taking a deeper look at it

Comment: No, it will enable you to secure your data using the UID that is generated by the Firebase Anonymous Authentication, in the same way you have done if would implement Firebase Authentication with a provider. The benefit here is, that you don't need to request any personal data from the user.

Comment: If you understand Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-handle-firebase-authentication-in-clean-architecture-using-jetpack-compose-e9929c0e31f8) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseAnonymousAuthentication).

Comment: Got it. I'm working with Java.

Comment: Thank you alex.

Comment: You're very welcome, MãĴď!

Comment: I just realized. Do I need to change my model? to support the auto generated ID ?

the rules can stay the way they are now?

Comment: Yes, you have to change the rules.  I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-fix-firestore-error-permission-denied-missing-or-insufficient-permissions-777d591f404) will help you understand the concept better.

Comment: Thank you again.